# Bootstrap 2 components is broken in safari browser with Win 7 os

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-2

Hi i am using bootstrap2, in Single button group the group is broken only in safari browser there is a gap between the button group see the attached image, please check and replay.

Thanks.

> http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/components.html[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its caused by the font-size. Safari in windows doesn't allow 0 as a value. A work around is use 0.1px which will make it look better but not perfect

Another option is not leaving white space in your HTML but that makes code less readable